# Find $b$ such that $P(−b<Z≤b)=0.90$ if $Z$ is a normal distribution

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve exercise 6.15-4 of Using R for Introductionary Statistics, which states that

If $Z$ is $\textit{Normal}(0,1)$, find $b$ such that $P(-b<Z≤b)=0.90$

From my understanding I can use the `qnorm` function for finding $b$, if this is correct I would be able to solve $P(Z≤b)=0.90$ by doing:

```
b = qnorm(0.9, mean=0, sd=1)
```

and I could also solve $P(-b<Z)=0.90$ by doing:

```
b = qnorm(0.9, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

I don't understand how I can get $b$ for both range conditions because the probability used to get $b$ is based of these two range conditions, so I don't know the probabilities for the two range conditions separately.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated, I am still very new to statistics and R :)

Comment: You can add a self-study tag for self-study or homework questions.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 cheers, added the tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
P(X<-b) + P(-b < X \leq b) + P(X \geq b) & = 1 \\
P(-b < X \leq b) & = 1 - \big(P(X<-b) + P(X \geq b)\big)
\end{align}
$$

Since normal distribution is symmetric around $X=0$, the right-hand side of the equation can be simplified into

$$
\begin{align}
P(-b < X \leq b) & = 1 - \big(P(X < -b) + P(X < -b)\big) \\
                 & = 1 - 2 \times P( X < -b)
\end{align}
$$

Plugging in $P(-b < X \leq b) = 0.9$,

$$
\begin{align}
0.9 &= 1 - 2 \times P(X < -b) \\
- 0.1 &= -2 \times P(X < -b) \\
0.05 &= P(X < -b)
\end{align}
$$

From here, the value of $-b$ can be obtained via `qnorm(0.05, mean=0, sd=1)`, that is $-1.644854$. Therefore, $b=1.644854$.

Comment: (−<≤)=0.9 , therefore −2×(<−)=0.9-1=-0.1, which gives (<−)=0.05 
so $b$ is `qnorm(0.05, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail = FALSE)` which gives $b=1.644854$?

Comment: Precisely! I will edit my answer to complete the explanation.

Comment: thanks a lot, I should've noticed the symmetry haha. Your explanation has been very helpful.